# Jquery - Getting trouble on double click because change in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. `onclick` I am changing the class of that button but when I double click its changing class. All my functionality `depend on current class`
how to disable double click or make the request complete on first click.

```
function data() {
    lastScrollTop = 0;
    document.getElementById("expand-dataset-btn").disabled = false;
    var id = event.target.id
    var allChildern = null
    if(!$(".id_"+event.target.id).hasClass('minus-symbol')){
        $(".id_"+event.target.id).removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol')
        $.ajax({

            },
            success : function(result) {

            }
         });
    }else{
        $(".id_"+event.target.id).addClass('plus-symbol').removeClass('minus-symbol')
        $.ajax({

            },
            success : function(result) {

            }
         });
    }
}
```

Calling function from controller like below

```
htmlDataId += "<a onclick=\"data()\" title='View' id="+row[primaryField]+">
```

Comment: May be you are going wrong in your flow. Put alert in function and trace. Every time it goes inside function.

Comment: If you can post your HTML as well

Comment: You should wait for ajax to complete. Change class after `success`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I tried that too. If I don't do that means the request goes to same method and that is fetching data again

Comment: What is this element? $(".id_"+event.target.id)

Comment: This is dynamic event call. `event.target.id` gives id of clicked element.

Comment: Yes, to give a valid answer we want your html as well.. according to your post there is no id defined on clicked element!

Comment: Well, I have edited code see mentioned `id="+row[primaryField]+"` There no html I have written. It will get from controller and convert it into html.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for ajax to complete

```
function data() {

    lastScrollTop = 0;
    document.getElementById("expand-dataset-btn").disabled = false;
    var id = event.target.id;
    var allChildern = null;

    if($(".id_"+ id).hasClass("disable"))
    {
          event.preventDefault();             
    }

    if(!$(".id_"+ id).hasClass('minus-symbol')){
        //make control disable
        $(".id_"+ id).addClass('disabled');
        $.ajax({

            },
            success : function(result) {
            //change here after success
            $(".id_"+ id).removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol');
            //remove control disable
            $(".id_"+ id).removeClass('disabled');
         });
    }else{
       //make control disable
        $(".id_"+ id).attr('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({

            },
            success : function(result) {
            //change here after success
              $(".id_"+ id).addClass('plus-symbol').removeClass('minus-symbol');
              //remove control disable
              $(".id_"+ id).attr('disabled', false);
            }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Second ajax call only performs if class is not setted. This will solve his problem for instant second call / double click problem.

Comment: No! ajax calls do nothing here!

Comment: He made changes class not basis of class this thing works.

Comment: This will not work. as if i don't change class then its calling same ajax method. that is also same issue

Comment: And this `(".id_"+event.target.id)` will not work in sucess block

Comment: please change my edited code. Also you should use disable till first call complete. Make condition based on disable.

Comment: and attribute `<a>` doesn't support disable attribute.

Comment: use `e.preventDefault();` to disable `<a>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98337/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-soham-shetty).

Answer (score 0):

what you need is "throttle" function or "debounce" function.

> Throttling is a means by which we can limit the number of times a function can be called in a given period. For instance, we may have a method that should be called no more than 5 times per second.

you can either use underscore [underscore official website](http://underscorejs.org/)

or

you can use the following codes:

```
/*trigger specific eventhandler when the event is idle for specific time*/
function debounce(fn, delay, self) {
    var timer = null;
    return function () {
        var context = self ? self : this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
//use in the following way
 $input.on('click',debounce(clickCallback,250));
```

then if the second "click" event triggered within 250ms, it will be ignored